# How to use MELT or FFMPEG for layering of a video (i.e. shifting an overlay of the same video by one frame to remove flicerking from LEDs)?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, linux, command-line

I am looking for a possibility to remove the flickering from LEDs on a video under Linux on the commandline. To do that one would have to

- Put the video on one track
- Put the same video on a second track with 1-2 frames delay
- Overlay the second track with 50% transparency
- Use the audio from one of the tracks

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would carry that out, like this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex \
  "[0]split=2[base][shifted]; \
   [shifted]setpts=PTS+1/TB/FRAME_RATE,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.50[shifted]; \
   [base][shifted]overlay"   out.mp4
```

`setpts=PTS+1/TB/FRAME_RATE` delays the overlay by 1 frame. Change the `1` to adjust delay.

`format=yuva444p` makes sure there's an alpha channel.

`colorchannelmixer=aa=0.50` sets the alpha to 50%.

I haven't specified any encoding parameters, so the defaults will be used.